# Addressable memory and relation with buffer overflows

Tags: c, memory-management, buffer-overflow

Reading about buffer overflows, I came across the sample code given below:-

```
void function(int a, int b, int c) {
char buffer1[5];
char buffer2[10];
}

void main() {
 function(1,2,3);
}
```

It's from the famous smashing the stack for fun and profit article I guess. (Reference: http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html)

The article says that to allocate space for buffer1 and buffer2, 20 bytes are required (8 bytes for buffer1 and 12 bytes for buffer2) since memory addresses can only be accessed in multiples of word size (1 word = 4 bytes in this case).

But I recall that memory is byte addressable I.e. I can access 1 byte at a time from memory. I related this with processor's bitness. e.g. a 32 bit processor can access 2^32 memory locations and since 1 memory location holds 1 byte(8 bits), the total addressable memory for a 32 bit processor equals (2^32)/(1024*1024*1024) = 4096 MB = 4GB.

Since in the above example, both buffer1 and buffer2 are of type char which let's say requires 1 byte, then why can't we allocate 5 bytes and 10 bytes for buffer1 and buffer2 respectively?

Why is memory access limited to multiples of word size?

Comment: Remember that the paper you reference is old (from 1996) when many popular processors didn't allow non-word-aligned memory access, or non-word-aligned access incurred severe penalties. These days it's no longer that much of a problem.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Even Intel x86 CPU? (since the article uses this under linux)

Comment: Yes, even the x86 used to have very bad performance on unaligned memory access. These days it doesn't matter that much because of the caches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing - *memory **access*** is not limited to word size.

As you point out you are free to access memory in the finest granularity your respective CPU supports - in most cases this will be bytes.

However for local variables in C the **alignment** rules are a little specific.
The whole word-access limitation is related to the fact that the function locals are placed on the so called *stack*.

The stack is provided by the CPU to temporarily store and retrieve register values in memory and each program is given its own memory to use as stack space.
It's common / in some cases required to access the stack in exactly the register size your CPU uses so you don't accidentialy clobber up the push / pop access the CPU uses.
On 32bit systems that access-size is *4 byte per register*, for 64bit its 8 byte.

So in your example the function's stack may look something like this on an Intel CPU *(Depending on the OS)*:

```
|---   function's stack bottom  ---|
| 4 byte Code-Segment index        |
| 4 byte return address            |
| 4 byte buffer1[0..3]             |
| 1 byte buffer1[4],    3 byte pad |
| 4 byte buffer2[0..3]             |
| 4 byte buffer2[4..7]             |
| 2 byte buffer2[8..9], 2 byte pad |
|---   function's stack top     ---|
```

The padding bytes are required so that when your program is running and using the stack from inside your function it'll still by properly aligned (and trust me it will use it a lot ;) ).

E.g. a push / pop would still result in a 4byte aligned address.

*Remember: this aligning rules only apply to stack space - global or static variables can be on odd memory locations (unlikely, but possible)*

I hope this was not to techie / low-level.

**[EDIT]**
The relation to buffer overflows here becomes clear if you think about the following thing:
If you know the memory and stack layout you can manipulate things like the *return address*.
As you see by over- / underflowing the buffer's you could easily change values located above / below them on the stack.
In most cases this will crash your code but if executed properly you could also put some executable code on the stack / somewhere in memory and alter the function's return address to jump to that code instead back to where it was called.

Comment: So, how does the CPU know how many bytes are allocated for padding and how many contain real data? Does it check from the size specified in the code?

Comment: To be honest for the local variables like buffer1/2 the CPU doesn't know this. That's up to your C compiler to figure out and keep track of.

Comment: The compiler will access the aligned stack contents as granular as it has to. The CPU (using push / pop) will always add / remove a fixed byte amount and actually don't care about which of the bytes are data. The difference is simply the way of accessing it - either by push / pop or by direct memory access.

Comment: since operations in the cpu will require the use of registers to pass data, how does the compiler adjust these registers so that the cpu interprets the data correctly?

Comment: There are different operations to access register content and (at least an Intel CPUs) there can be differently sized access versions of the same register - e.g. you have RAX (64bit) the lower 32bits are accessible as EAX. That in turn has 16 lower bits accessible as AX which can be fully access as AH / AL for 8bit higher / 8bit lower. But please note you don't always require to use the registers to pass data. Passing in memory is fine and most operations a CPU can perform will accept memory locations instead.

Comment: Okay, i'll accept your answer. Just one last question. How will 24 bits of data be passed in registers or for that matter any data size which is not a multiple of 8 bits? I agree that memory can be used to pass any amount of data.

Comment: Sorry, had to Drive home first... For 24bit you would load the next biggest register. In this case 32bits the unused bits will become zeros. Internally you don't really have a 24bit data type so it would work on 32bits anyway. (With the notable exception of floating point types but they have special registers). If you're interested at this level of machine interaction I suggest you visit http://wiki.osdev.org - toy kernels really help to understand the CPU guts (and they have tutorials there).

Comment: I've accepted your answer. Many thanks for the helpful link. I'm really interested in OS/Machine internals.